# cannot login to ask ubuntu

Tags: discussion, login

This page:

https://askubuntu.com/users/login

Has been changed and no longer has a place to enter login info.

I have a login id.  Should I create another one?

I cannot send this message using my current email.  It demands that I login!

Then this page refuses to submit.  I doesn,t like AskUbunty
,
vince@folkways.com

Answer (score 5):

Click "Login with Stack Exchange", or one of the other login options if you signed up using a different method such as your Google account.